# Focus to next text input or submit not working in custom text input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

First of all here is my custom component.

```
 return (
      <View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>

        <TextField
          style={styles.inputText}
          autoCapitalize={this.props.autoCapitalize}
          ref={this.props.ref}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onFocus={() => this.setState({isFocus:true})}
          onBlur={() => this.setState({isFocus:false})}
          value={this.state.text}
          label={this.props.placeholder}
          secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
          blurOnSubmit={this.props.blurOnSubmit}
          keyboardType={this.props.keyboardType}
          returnKeyType={this.props.returnKeyType}
          textContentType={this.props.textContentType}
        //  onSubmitEditing={this.props.focus(this.props.textInput)}
          onSubmitEditing={this.props.onSubmit}
          placeholderTextColor='grey'
          onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText ? this.props.onChangeText : (text) => this.setState({ text })}
          editable={this.props.editable}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

Now on submit the email field i want to make focus to password field and on submit on password i want to submit the form .

Here is the code for that :

```
<MaterialTextInput
             placeholder="Email"
           //  ref={(input) => { this.emailInput = input; }}
             ref={ref => (this.emailInput = ref)}
             onSubmit = {() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
             onChangeText={(text) => this.handleEmailchange(text)}/>


          <MaterialTextInput
             placeholder="Password"
             ref={ref => this.passwordInput = ref}
             onSubmit = {() => this.submit()}
             onChangeText={(text) => this.handlePasswordchange(text)}/>
```

But this does not works . 
It gives error ,

```
this.passwordInput.focus is undefined
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Because your component `<MaterialTextInput>` in `this.passwordInput` is actually a `<View>` not `<TextField>`. And View don't have any method named `focus()`!!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `ref` directly in your custom component. You have to declare your custom component as below :

```js
const MaterialTextInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
      <TextField
        style={styles.inputText}
        autoCapitalize={this.props.autoCapitalize}
        ref={ref} // Change Here also
        autoCorrect={false}
        onFocus={() => this.setState({isFocus:true})}
        onBlur={() => this.setState({isFocus:false})}
        value={this.state.text}
        label={this.props.placeholder}
        secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
        blurOnSubmit={this.props.blurOnSubmit}
        keyboardType={this.props.keyboardType}
        returnKeyType={this.props.returnKeyType}
        textContentType={this.props.textContentType}
      //  onSubmitEditing={this.props.focus(this.props.textInput)}
        onSubmitEditing={this.props.onSubmit}
        placeholderTextColor='grey'
        onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText ? this.props.onChangeText : (text) => this.setState({ text })}
        editable={this.props.editable}
      />
    </View>
  )
})
```

Now, you can use ref in your component.

Comment: Have you change this line also `ref={ref}` ?

Comment: Undefined is not an object materialTextInput

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ref` directly in your custom component. Use `React.forwardRef()`. Also don't use `this.props.` but use `props.` as your component isn't class-based.

> Because your component `<MaterialTextInput>` in `this.passwordInput` is actually a `<View>` not `<TextField>`. And View don't have any method named `focus()`!!!

Above isn't the case anymore.

1) Export your **Component** from its file e.g. *MaterialTextInput.js*

```
export default MaterialTextInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
    <TextField ref={ref}
    onSubmitEditing={props.onSubmit}
    ...
    />
  </View>
));
```

2) Then import you component:

```
import MaterialTextInput from 'MaterialTextInput';
```

3) And use your component as you did

```
...
<MaterialTextInput ref={ref => this.emailInput = ref}
onSubmit={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
... />

<MaterialTextInput ref={ref => this.passwordInput = ref}
onSubmit={() => this.submit()}
... />
```

Comment: I commented View and now main is TextField but that also not works

Comment: Also what if i want to put textinput and text in same component in same view then how to do that

Comment: Just added `React.forwardRef` as in @K.Bharda's answer. Check it!

Comment: Can't find variable MaterialTextInput

Comment: Where are you using your component? Are you in same file or have you imported the component???

Comment: i have imported the component from another file

Comment: then you must have exported your component. Change `const MaterialTextInput` to `export default MaterialTextInput`

Comment: also provide in your question what you've changed so far in your code and where are you having issues